# Why Python scope my variable outside my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i start with Python. I like to try new language. So i've got a "simple" problem about scope and Python.

Here is a recursive function

```
def foo(myarray)
  if myarray == False: 
    myarray = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(5)]
    myarray[0][0] = 1
  "some code ..."
  foo(myarray)

myarray = False
foo(myarray)
```

I don't want to share my var "myarray" in global env. I juste want Python scope "myarray" only in the function not outside. But Python shared "myarray" as it were a global var. How can restrict the scope to the function ?

Comment: Your code has multiple syntax errors.

Comment: Did you get a maximum recursion depth error?

Comment: no, this is just an example of my code and only to explain my problem

Comment: This answer helped me to solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/24572213/1913545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding the myriad of syntax errors, your `myarray` variable seems to be declared globally and that's why it has global scope?

Comment: Should i put my function in a class ?

Comment: You could but a class isn't strictly necessary `. The 'myarray' variable is defined in global scoped due to the indentation on the second last line in your snippet. The trick is to remember that Python uses indentation to differentiate code blocks.

Comment: Can i do something like : `foo(list(myarray))`  to prevent Python share 'myarray' ?

Comment: You could define it inside the function instead.